# .htaccess: Allow specific URL

Tags: .htaccess, server

I have an angularJS site and the .htaccess file have been configured to redirect all traffic from mysite.se/* to mysite.se/index.html.

It also configured with prerender.io to let search engines to access the site.

**Question: I want to add a blog to blog.mysite.se, and the problem is of course that it will be redirected to mysite.se/index.html. What do I need to add to the .htaccess file to let through the blog.mysite.se?**

Thanks

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MYSITE\.se$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.MYSITE.se%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# If requested resource exists as a file or directory
# (REQUEST_FILENAME is only relative in virtualhost context, so not usable)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
# Go to it as is
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If non existent
# If path ends with / and is not just a single /, redirect to without the trailing /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R,QSA,L]      

# Handle Prerender.io
RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "kEJ0CC1gMnj6V0J4u8xu"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

# Proxy the request
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://service.prerender.io/http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [P,L]

# If non existent
# Accept everything on index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule **just below `RewriteEngine On` line** to skip `blog` subdomain from current rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST ^blog\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# rest of rules here
```